# How to create public link of the autodesk viewer from ACC docs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Currently we are trying to create a public link of the ACC viewer [image: ACC1]. But when we shared the link at that time it will directly give option for downloading the files instead of the 3D viewer[image: ACC2].

Comment: From the ACC product? or from the API?